# Error DPY-3010 when connecting python-oracledb to Oracle DB 11.2

Tags: python, database, oracle, python-oracledb

If you try to connect to Oracle Database 11.2 using [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/)'s default
'Thin' mode you will get the error:

```
DPY-3010: connections to this database server version are not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode
```

How can I connect to this old version of Oracle Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python-oracledb's default Thin mode can connect to Oracle Database 12.1 or later.  If
you want to connect to Oracle Database 11.2 you need to enable Thick mode by
calling `oracledb.init_oracle_client()` in your code.  See the user documentation [Enabling python-oracledb Thick mode](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-python-oracledb-thick-mode)

Oracle DB 11.2 is very old.  There are newer, free versions of Oracle Database
available, such as [Oracle Database 23c Free](https://www.oracle.com/database/free/) and the [XE 21c "Express Edition"](https://www.oracle.com/au/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html).